# DataSet and query with IN as List<int>

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset, tableadapter

My problem is that i have DataSet with Tables and i want to return values

```
'where DocumentType IN (@list)'
```

, but @list is like :

```
string.Join(",",DocTypes.List1);
```

I have tried to use it like
`SELECT........ WHERE DocumentType IN (@list)` (in DataSet table adapter wizard), but when im executing Fill method, have ann error:

```
adapter1.Fill(ds.allDocuments, string.Join(",",DocTypes.List1);
```

Parameter 2 should be int, not string.
Declare also wouldnt work in dataset..

Any help?

Comment: Please when you have an error, always add the exception and stack track so we can understand the nature of the error. I'll restrain myself from downvoting as it is Monday...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Split` function, then this works:

```
WHERE
    ([DocumentType IN] IN
        (SELECT  Item
         FROM    dbo.Split(@list, ',') AS DocumentSplit))
```

This is a possible implementation of the table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @IDTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(50))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @tempItemList = REPLACE (@tempItemList, ' ', '')
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @IDTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

Maybe you need to ensure manually in the parameters of the tableadapter that it's `DbType` is string:

[image]

Comment: OTOH, shoudn't most decent .NET DB providers support a list as parameter type when filling in for an IN statement?

Comment: @flq: No, no provider supports collections since databases "understand" only tables. http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Comment: Yeah, there is a block "Passing Table-Valued Parameters from ADO .NET" in that text, sounds to me it should indeed be possible to pass some sort of collection-type object into the parameter.

Comment: I have tried to use last solution from that response (just changed dbTYpe to string), but that throwing exception "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '9,4' to data type int."

Comment: @AdamTruszkowski: Yes, because the column is of type int, but you need a split function anyway as shown above. At least that approach with all versions >= sql-server 2005.

Comment: @AdamTruszkowski: Note that you might need to reset the `DbType` to `String` always when you change the `TableAdapter` (not only this query). That's because of a bug in the designer which maps to the type of the column you are referring to(in this case `DocumentType` which is probably an `int`). Just keep that in mind.